# Are composite REST (or composite graph) subject to rate limits (in addition to the API request limits & allocations)?

Tags: rest-api, limits, composite, composite-graph

In additions to details given in [API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) & [Composite Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm), are the composite REST (or composite graph) requests also subject to rate limits (i.e. per hour & per user; considering the requests use a session ID from Salesforce). Couldn't find any definitive documentation around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link you posted is the general rule for **all** API calls, no matter what type, including the Composite, Composite Tree, and Composite Graph API calls. Each API call counts as one call towards the daily limit, which is metered over a 24-hour rolling window. Note that Lightning, Visualforce, and Aura server calls are *not* considered API calls for the purposes of these limits.

Some APIs do have additional restrictions, such as the login method (limited to once per second), and Chatter (limited to one polling call per minute), etc, that will be called out on those specific documentation pages. If no other restrictions are listed, the global API Request Limits and Allocations rules apply.

Comment: I believe the [Chatter Rate Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_chatter_rest.htm) are applicable for composite APIs as well. Will update here if I'm able to confirm the same.